# How to autocomplete tag names containing a colon?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, tags

Sometimes I want to autocomplete a tag name containing a colon, for example `g:netrw_gx`.

I've added to the `'tags'` option the location of the `tags` file of the main documentation (which on my machine seems to be `/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/tags`):

```
set tags+=$VIMRUNTIME/doc/tags
```

The default mapping to autocomplete a tag name is `<C-x><C-]>`.

The problem is if I type `g:net` and then hit `<C-x><C-]>`, Vim decides that the tag name begins after the colon, so the candidates which are suggested in the pop-up menu all begin with `net`, while I want candidates beginning with `g:net`.

I think the reason for this is given in an excerpt from `:h ctrl-x_ctrl-]`:

```
            Alphabetic characters and characters in 'iskeyword' are used
            to decide which characters are included in the tag
            name (same as for a keyword).
```

When looking for the tag name to complete, Vim takes probably all the characters from the cursor position back to the first character which is not in the `'iskeyword'` option.
And a colon is not in `'isk'`, as the output of `:echo &isk` is `@,48-57,_,192-255,#` which doesn't contain `:` or `58` (ascii code of `:`).

I don't want to change the value of `'isk'` as I suspect it would break many things (text-objects, plugins).

How can I autocomplete tag names containing a colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you prefer to avoid changing `'isk'` *permanently*, but what about changing it during the autocompletion?

```
function! CustomComplTag()
   setlocal isk+=:
   call feedkeys("\<c-x>\<c-]>", "n")
endfunction
augroup CustomComplTagAutcmd
   au!
   autocmd CompleteDone * setlocal isk-=:
augroup END

inoremap <C-x><C-]> <C-o>:call CustomComplTag()<CR>
```

You could also check the plugins that use ["CompleteHelper : Generic functions to support custom insert mode completions"](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914), maybe one of them does what you want, or is close enough so you can write a patch.