# How do I complete a WORD?

Tags: autocompletion

I use the complete function a lot. I have not found a solution to complete a WORD yet. For example, in LaTeX, I use the following expression:

```
T_{R_{delta}}
```

If I type `T` and then <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+n</kbd>, it wouldn't complete the whole thing.

I know I could use

```
:set iskeyword+=_:; etc.
```

but I want this behaviour just in this situation.

I am looking for a complete mechanism which completes everything like `vW` would visualize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a similar question a few weeks ago (how to complete a tag name containing a colon) and here was the [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6816/4939).

---

Your question is slightly different as you don't want to temporarily add a colon to the value of `'iskeyword'` but all characters which can appear inside a WORD.

Here's a different version of the original answer which redefines the behavior of `<C-X><C-N>` to autocomplete WORDS instead of words:

```
inoremap <C-X><C-N> <C-O>:call <SID>CustomKeyword(join(map(range(char2nr('!'),char2nr('~')), 'nr2char(v:val)'), ''))<CR><C-X><C-N>

function! s:CustomKeyword(chars) abort
    for char in split(a:chars, '\zs')
        execute 'setlocal iskeyword+=' . char2nr(char)
    endfor
    augroup custom_keyword
        autocmd!
        autocmd CompleteDone * setlocal iskeyword< | autocmd! custom_keyword
    augroup END
endfunction
```

The characters inside the string that you pass as an argument to the function `CustomKeyword()` will be added to the buffer-local value of `'isk'`, and the autocmd will reset the option once the completion is done by copying the global value into the buffer-local one (`setlocal iskeyword<`), as well as remove itself (`| autocmd! custom_keyword`).

Besides, you want to complete WORDS whose characters should be any printable character except a whitespace.
According to this [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), it seems the first printable character is the exclamation mark `!` and the last is the tilde `~`.
Thus, the string of printable characters could be obtained with the following code:

```
join(map(range(char2nr('!'),char2nr('~')), 'nr2char(v:val)'), '')
```

Which is the string passed as an argument to `CustomKeyword()` inside the `{rhs}` of the previous mapping whose `{lhs}` is `<C-X><C-N>`.

---

Note that you could reuse the `CustomKeyword()` function to change `'isk'` in any way.
For example, if you wanted to autocomplete tag names containing a colon, you could install the following mapping:

```
inoremap <C-X><C-]> <C-O>:call <SID>CustomKeyword(':')<CR><C-X><C-]>
```

The general syntax would be:

```
inoremap {lhs} <C-O>:call <SID>CustomKeyword('characters_to_add_to_isk')<CR>{lhs}
```

Where `{lhs}` is the keys you hit to trigger the completion (`<C-X><C-N>`, `<C-X><C-]>`, ...).

---

If you want to preserve the original behavior of `<C-X><C-N>`, and use another `{lhs}` to trigger the custom completion, for example `<C-X><C-A>`, you could use this mapping:

```
inoremap <C-X><C-A> <C-O>:call <SID>CustomKeyword(join(map(range(char2nr('!'),char2nr('~')), 'nr2char(v:val)'), ''))<CR><C-X><C-N>
```

You just have to change the first `<C-X><C-N>` in the original `{lhs}`, but not the second one in the `{rhs}`.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to not map it to <C-X><C-N> in order to maintain its original function. I would like to use a combination which isnt used by the completion system like <C-X><C-A>. Unfortunately this doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe `<C-X><C-U>` would work. Usually it's used in combination with a custom completion function whose name is defined by the option `'completefunc'`. Edit: ah no it doesn't seem to work. I'm gonna try something else, sorry.

Comment: @user3394244 I've edited the answer to include a mapping which uses `<C-X><C-A>`, it seems to work. You just have to change the first `<C-X><C-N>` in the original `{lhs}`, but not the second one in the `{rhs}`.

Comment: WORD completion with "@" in it doesn't work. Although its in the ASCII chart.